# PDF of $ | \sum_{k=1}^{n}{|h_k||g_k|\exp\left( j \theta_k \right)} |^2$ for small values of $n$ and $Q$?

Tags: pr.probability, probability-distributions, closed-form-expressions

Given the following function of random variables

$$f = \left|\sum_{k=1}^{n}{|h_k||g_k|\exp\left( j \theta_k \right)} \right|^2,$$
where $h_1, \cdots, h_n$ and $g_1, \cdots, h_n$ are i.i.d. random variables following the complex Gaussian distribution $\mathcal{CN}(0, \sigma_{h}^2)$ and $\mathcal{CN}(0, \sigma_{g}^2)$ and $\theta_1, \cdots, \theta_n$ $\in [\frac{-\pi}{Q}, \frac{\pi}{Q}]$ are i.i.d. uniformly distributed random variables with probability density function (PDF) given by $\frac{Q}{2\pi}$, where $Q$ is a integer number greater than 0. Additionally, we assume that $h_k$, $g_k$ and $\theta_k$ are independent for all values of $k$.

**UPDATED on 10/01/2020**

Based on my simulations I know that the PDF of $r$, which is defined as
$$ r = \left|\sum_{k=1}^{n}{|h_k||g_k|\exp\left( j \theta_k \right)} \right|, $$ can be accurately approximated by a Gamma random variable even for small values of $n$, and $Q$, $e.g.$, $n=1$ and $Q=4$. Therefore, the PDF of $f = r^2$ can be approximated as $$ P_{n}(f) = \frac{1}{2 \Gamma(\kappa)\Theta^{\kappa}} f^{\left(\frac{\kappa-2}{2} \right)} \exp\left(-\frac{\sqrt{f}}{\Theta}\right), f > 0.$$

However, I'm not being able to find the $\kappa$ and $\Theta$, $i.e.$, shape and scale, parameters of the Gamma random variable.

This problem arises from the study on wireless communications channels and is of great importance to the research community.

Comment: in one of your earlier [questions](https://mathoverflow.net/q/347885/11260) you mentioned drawing from a Nagakami distribution, rather than from a Gaussian distribution; is there a reason you switched? (I am asking, because that earlier question gave the same motivation from "wireless communication".)

Comment: @CarloBeenakker, thanks for your reply. Nakagami channels are only one of several possible channel models. I thought it would be easier to start from the simpler Rayleigh channel, which is described by the absolute values of $g$ and $h$.

Comment: Just to be sure for the definition of the law of $\theta_i$, Is it that $\theta_i\in [0,\frac{2\pi}{Q}]$?

Comment: @RaphaelB4, $\theta_{k} \in [\frac{-\pi}{Q}, \frac{\pi}{Q}]$. I've just updated the quaestion with this information.Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

• ***n* $\mathbf{\gg}$ *1*:**

The variable $f=r^2$ is the square of the distance $r$ from the origin after $n$ steps of a random walk on the plane with random direction [$\theta$ uniformly in $(0,2\pi)$] and mean squared step size $s^2$ given by
$$s^2=\mathbb{E}(|h|^2||g|^2)=\mathbb{E}(|h|^2|)\mathbb{E}(|g|^2)=\sigma_h^2\sigma_g^2.$$
For $n\gg 1$ the distribution of $r$ is a Maxwell distribution and hence the distribution of $f$ is exponential,
$$P_n(r)=\frac{2r}{ns^2}e^{-\frac{r^2}{ns^2}}\Rightarrow P_n(f)=\frac{1}{ns^2}e^{-\frac{f}{ns^2}}.$$
So  for $n\gg 1$ the distribution $P_n(f)$ is a [Gamma distribution](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gamma_distribution) with shape $k=1$ and scale $\theta=n\sigma_h^2\sigma_g^2$.

---

• ***n* $=$ *1*:**

For $n=1$ one can calculate directly
$$P_1(r)=\int_0^\infty d|g|\int_0^\infty d|h|\, \delta(r-|gh|)P(|h|)P(|g|)$$
$$=(\sigma_h\sigma_g)^{-2}\int_0^\infty dh\, \frac{4r}{h} e^{-h^2/\sigma_h^2} e^{-(r/h)^2/\sigma_g^2}=\frac{4r}{\sigma_g^2\sigma_h^2}K_0\left(\frac{2r}{\sigma_g\sigma_h}\right),$$
with $K_0$ a Bessel function.
<sub>(I have used that the absolute value $|h|$ when $h$ is $\mathcal{CN}(0, 1)$ has distribution $p(|h|)=2|h|e^{-|h|^2}$.)</sub>
So for $n=1$ the distribution of $f=r^2$ is
$$P_1(f)=\frac{2}{\sigma_g^2\sigma_h^2}K_0\left(\frac{2\sqrt{f}}{\sigma_g\sigma_h}\right).$$

---

• **arbitrary *n*:**

A closed form for $P_n(r)$ exists for arbitrary $n$, see [The non-isotropic two-dimensional random walk](https://doi.org/10.1088/0959-7174/3/4/001), by B.C. Barber (1993):

$$P_n(f)=(\sigma_g\sigma_h)^{-n-1}\frac{2f^{(n-1)/2}}{\Gamma(n)}K_{n-1}\left(\frac{2\sqrt f}{\sigma_g\sigma_h}\right).$$

The large-$f$ decay is a stretched exponential $\propto e^{-2\sqrt{f}}$, so this cannot be precisely modeled by a Gamma distribution (which decays exponentially).

---

**anisotropic random walk:**

All of this was for an isotropic random walk, with $\theta_k$ at each step  uniformly distributed in $(-\pi,\pi)$. The parameter $Q>1$ restricts the angle to $(-\pi/Q,\pi/Q)$, so the scattering is peaked in the forward direction. For $n\gg 1$ the anisotropy can be accounted for by a rescaling of the mean squared step size,
$$s_Q^2=\frac{\sigma_h^2\sigma_g^2}{1-\langle \cos\theta\rangle},$$
where $\langle\cdots\rangle$ denotes the angular average. We have
$$\langle\cos\theta\rangle=\frac{Q}{2\pi}\int_{-\pi/Q}^{\pi/Q}\cos\theta\,d\theta=\frac{Q}{\pi}\sin(\pi/Q),$$
so we arrive at the distribution
$$P_n(f)=\frac{1}{ns_Q^2}e^{-\frac{f}{ns_Q^2}},\;\;s_Q^2=\frac{\sigma_h^2\sigma_g^2}{1-(Q/\pi)\sin(\pi/Q)}.$$
This is a Gamma distribution with shape $k=1$ and scale $\theta=ns_Q^2$.

For $n=1$ the distribution $P_1(f)$ is $Q$-independent, so the result $\propto K_0$ above still applies. For $n>1$ I presume the decay will still be a stretched exponential, but I do not have an exact result as for $Q=1$.

Comment: Dear, I was wondering if there is a way to find the $\kappa$ and $\theta$ parameters of the Gamma random variable, which I found to the a very good approximation for $f$ even for small $n$, $e.g.$, $n=1$.

Comment: for $n\gg 1$ the parameters of the Gamma distribution are shape $=1$ and scale $=n\sigma_h^2\sigma_g^2$. For $n=1$ I find a Bessel function distribution, which for small $f$ diverges logarithmically as $-\ln f$ and for large $f$ decays as a stretched exponential $e^{-\sqrt f}$. So this is definitely not a Gamma distribution, but if you insist you might take the shape $k=1/2$, which gives a reasonable fit (see plot). Interpolating between $k=1/2$ for $n=1$ and $k=1$ for $n\geq 10$, with $\theta=n\sigma_h^2\sigma_g^2$, should then cover the entire range of $n$. Is that satisfactory?

Comment: Dear Carlo, $Q$ in this case is the number of discrete phase angles the transmitter can generate in order to cancel the phase angles of $h$ and $g$, $i.e.$, the double Rayleigh channel. In some systems, the transmitter can not generate the exact phase so that the phase of the double Rayleigh channel can be canceled. Therefore, $Q > 1$, in fact, some implementations start from $Q = 4$

Comment: I've added the $Q>1$ case for $n\gg 1$, which is a Gamma distribution with shape $=1$ and scale $=n\sigma_h^2\sigma_g^2[1-(Q/\pi)\sin(\pi/Q)]^{-1}$. I have also added the exact result for all $n$ for $Q=1$ (in terms of a Bessel function $K_{n-1}$).

Comment: Dear Carlo, thanks a lot for your answer. I'd like to kindly ask you, if possible, to detail the intermediate steps for the "anisotropic random walk" part of the answer. I'm not familiar with the random walk and I'd like to learn more about it as I noticed it helped in several answers here at mathoverflow.

Comment: there is not really much more to say: in the limit $n\gg 1$ of many steps the random walk satisfies a diffusion equation, which contains only a single parameter, the diffusion constant $D$, or equivalently, the mean free path $l$. For isotropic scattering in $d$ dimensions $D$ is related to the mean-square-displacement $s^2$ by $s^2=2dD\tau$ (with $\tau$ the time between steps). For anisotropic scattering you should replace $D$ by $D/(1-\langle\cos\theta\rangle)$, or equivalently, replace $l$ by the [transport mean free path](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Transport_length).

Comment: I see, thanks for the updates! Do you think we can apply the same approach if $h$ and $g$ are Nakagami-m distributed?

Comment: certainly, once you are in the diffusion regime $n\gg 1$ all you need to know is the mean-square displacement, it does not matter how the step size is distributed.

Comment: It makes total sense. Dank U wel!

Comment: Dear Carlo, your solution for the anisotropic case and n $\gg 1$ works fine, however, it works for really big values of $n$. I'm working with $n =$ 8, 16, 32, I tout the case for $n \gg 1$ would be a good approximation for such values but it isn't. I'm wondering if there is a general case, for any value of $n$ in the anisotropic case.

Comment: if you have more and more forward scattering, for larger and larger $Q$, you will need larger and larger $n$ to reach the diffusion regime, simply because you need backscattering for diffusion and backscattering is suppressed for large $Q$; if $Q$ is large and $n$ is small a better approximation would be to ignore backscattering altogether, and just fix the angles $\theta_k$ at zero.

Comment: But what about if $Q$ is also small, for example, equal to 4?

Comment: I tried to apply the rescaling to the anisotropic case for any value of $n$ but it was to no avail.

Comment: Dear Carlo, I've just updated the question with some new results for small values of $n$ and $Q$, however, I'm still looking for the $\kappa$ and $\Theta$ parameters of the Gamma PDF that can approximate $r$. Thanks.

Comment: I don't understand how this would work: for $Q=1$ I have written down the exact $P_n(f)$ for any $n$; this has a finite nonzero $n$-dependent limit $P_n(f=0)=1/(n-1)$ for $n>1$; how can this be fitted by the Gamma distribution?

Comment: In fact, $r$ is approximated by the Gamma PDF not $f$. You are right, for $Q=1$ it doesn´t work, however, I'm interested in the $Q > 1$ case for any $n$ value.

Comment: for $n=1$ the exact distribution is $Q$-independent, and $P(f)\propto \ln f^{-1}$ for small $f$ --- the Gamma distribution can only give power laws, no logarithm.

Comment: I understand, but the point is that I'm looking for the PDF when $n$ small but greater than 1. Your anisotropic solution works only when $n \to \infty$, which is not what I'm looking for right now. The approximation I have found has been working fine for several $Q$ and $n$ values, the only problem is that I have to infer $\kappa$ and $\Theta$ from the mean and variance averages of a Monte Carlo simulation.

Answer (score 1):

I understand the answer I gave, which involves either exact or asymptotic results, is not quite what the OP was looking for, so let me try to suggest a different approach. The question is: please find parameters $k$ and $\theta$ such that 
$$p_{k,\theta}(r) = \frac{r^{k-1}}{ \Gamma(k)\theta^{k}}  e^{-r/\theta}$$
approximates the distribution of the distance from the origin after $n$ steps in a certain anisotropic random walk on the two-dimensional plane. The random walk has step size distribution 
$$F(r)=\frac{4r}{\sigma_g^2\sigma_h^2}K_0\left(\frac{2r}{\sigma_g\sigma_h}\right)$$
and scattering angle uniformly distributed in $(-\pi/Q,\pi/Q)$.

The first step would be to eliminate the parameters $\sigma_g$ and $\sigma_h$ by rescaling 
$$r=R\sigma_g\sigma_h$$ 
The distribution $P_{n,Q}(R)$ of $R$ no longer depends on $\sigma_g$ or $\sigma_h$. It only contains the two parameters $n$ and $Q$, both $\in\mathbb{N}$, and we wish to fit this with the two-parameter distribution $p_{k,\theta}(R)$, with $k,\theta\in\mathbb{R}$.

The next thing to note is that in the context in which the problem appears, only a few integer values of $Q$ are of relevance. We also have exact asymptotic results for $n\gg 1$, so if we would take 100 different combinations of $Q$ and $n$ we would have covered much of the relevant parameter space. The fitting procedure could be simplified by fitting first for large $R$, to extract $\theta$, and then for small $R$, to extract $k$. I guess this could be automated to a large extent, or perhaps even done by hand.

---

As an example, I tried this for $Q=1$, when I know the exact $P_{n,1}(r)$. The Mathematica command

`Manipulate[
 LogPlot[{(4*r^n/Gamma[n])*BesselK[n-1, 2*r], 
(r^(k-1)/(Gamma[k]*t^k))*Exp[-r/t]},{r,0,20}],
 {n,2,10,1}, {k,0.1,5}, {t,0.1,5}]`

provides for a convenient way to do the fit by sliding the parameters $n$, $k$, and $t\equiv\theta$. Here is a representative output for $n=3,5,8$:

[image]
[image]
[image]

I followed up on the suggestion by the OP to carry out the fit by adjusting the parameters $k$ and $\theta$ such that the first two moments of $R$ agree. For $Q=1$ we have the exact result
$$\mathbb{E}(R)=\frac{\sqrt{\pi } \,\Gamma \left(n+\frac{1}{2}\right)}{2 \Gamma (n)},\;\;\mathbb{E}(R^2)=n,$$
to be compared with the Gamma-distribution result $\mathbb{E}(R)=k\theta$,  $\mathbb{E}(R^2)=k(1+k)\theta^2$.
I show the comparison for $n=5$, when $k=2.955$ and $\theta=0.654$, see the plot below. It seems this fitting procedure is worse than the unconstrained fit (with $k=3.6$ and $\theta=0.55$) carried out above.

[image]

Comment: Dear Carlo, thanks once more for the new answer. What I'm trying to do right now is to find $\kappa$ and $\Theta$ based on the Gamma's distribution definition of $\mu$ and $\sigma^2$, $i.e.$, $\mu = \kappa \Theta$ and $\sigma^2 = \kappa \Theta^2$. The only problem I've found is how to find the expectation of $r$. If you have any jint on that I would be very glad!

Comment: If we find two different moments for $Q \neq 1$, for example the mean and variance, we will be able to find $\kappa$ and $\Theta$. I will post an expansion for $r^2$.

Comment: By using the following identity $r^2 = | \sum_{i=1}^{N}{z_{i} e^{\theta_{1}}} |^2 = \sum_{i=1}^{N}{z_{i}^{2}} + 2\sum_{i=1}^{N}{\sum_{j=i+1}^{N}{z_{i}z_{j}\cos(\theta_{i}-\theta_{j})}}$ we can find the expectation of $r^2$. Then, if we find a different expectation we can use the two of them to figure out $\kappa$ and $\Theta$.

Comment: If another expectation is to hard to find, we could use the known expectation of $r^2$, isolate one of the parameters, plug it back into the gamma pdf and integrate the pdf from $-\infty$ to $\infty$ and with that find the second parameter.

Comment: what do you think?

Comment: I tried this for $Q=1$. The result is not very encouraging, a global fit produces much better results than the fit of the first two moments.

Comment: Dear Carlo, could you, please, share with me the steps you used to find the expectation of $r$? I'd like to apply it to the $Q > 1$ case and see what happens. In my simulations, when I use the statistics (based on Monte Carlo runs) of $r$ to find $\kappa$ and $\Theta$ for the $Q > 1$ case I always have a very good approximation.

Comment: for $Q=1$ I have an exact expression for $P(R)$ in terms of the $K_{n-1}$ Bessel function (see my other answer); from that I can immediately calculate all moments of $R$.

Comment: Would it be easier if $Q \to \infty$ ? In that case the term $e^{j\theta_i}$ would disappear.

Comment: for $Q\rightarrow\infty$ the variable $R$ is simply the sum of independent positive random numbers [i.i.d. with $p$-th moment $\Gamma(1+p/2)^2$]; that seems rather trivial.